# Using a Timer to Update a Label in an ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer

I have a label on my master page that I would like to see update every second, keeping track of the seconds elapsed. I have revised my question and have seen some progress but have a new problem.

I have restructured my code to include an ASP:Timer, Trigger, and AsyncPostBackTrigger (all wrapped within an UpdatePanel) but the update only seems to happen once... The default label text appears, is updated to "1" and then stays that way even though the back-end code continues to count upwards.

Back End:

```
Public intCounter As Integer = 0

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    getUserAccess()
    manageAccess()

End Sub

Protected Sub testTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles testTimer.Tick

    intCounter += 1
    lblTestTimer.Text = intCounter

End Sub
```

HTML:

```
        <div>
            <asp:Timer ID="testTimer" OnTick="testTimer_Tick" runat="server" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="testTimer" EventName="Tick"/>
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTestTimer" CssClass="ticketLabel" Text="Ticket Alert!" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Final Issue (Fixed): My interval was being reset on each page load, I changed the declaration to Shared and all is well. Thank you to @the_lotus for the help!**

Comment: You should really read about page life cycle. The server can't connect to the client like that. Usually, the timer is done on the client using javascript and call the server for the updated value. It's not like a winform where everything is run on the client.

Comment: @the_lotus I figured as much, that makes sense.. The final result will need to be a stored procedure running every 5 minutes to check if new tickets have come in and then alert the user via a label... Only gets more fun from here.

Comment: The Ajax controls includes a timer, I believe, which you could easily setup to refresh the updatepanel. Try to search for that online. I know I've done it before (just can't remember the details). You would declare the timer and configure it on your .aspx page, and then set the event in the code-behind file.

Comment: @the_lotus please see revised question and code, if I cant get this to work I will go the Javascript route

Comment: @haag1 your variable gets reset on every page load. Save the value in a session or make it shared.

Comment: @the_lotus I was just debugging through that part and noticed it as you were probably typing out that explanation. Thanks for all the help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really read about page life cycle. The server can't connect to the client like that. Usually, the timer is done on the client using javascript and call the server for the updated value. It's not like a winform where everything is run on the client.

Since you are using an UpdatePanel, you could probably use the asp:Timer to run a timer on the client.

Your variable also gets reset on every page load. Save the value in a session or make it shared.